# How can I fix the issue of showing the same tooltip value in all x-axis for area charts using ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly, geom-area

## R ggplotly geom_area (area chart) tooltip issue - showing same tooltip value in all x-axis.

I am facing tooltip issue in my projects while creating area charts using geom_area from ggplot package in R (for the tooltip, converted into plotly object using ggplotly() function from plotly package). for all x-axis, it is showing same tooltip value.

Please see the reproducible example code (this code is from [r graph gallery](https://r-graph-gallery.com/136-stacked-area-chart.html)).

```
# Packages
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

# create data
time <- as.numeric(rep(seq(1,7),each=7))  # x Axis
value <- runif(49, 10, 100)               # y Axis
group <- rep(LETTERS[1:7],times=7)        # group, one shape per group
data <- data.frame(time, value, group)

# stacked area chart
ggplotly(
  ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=value, fill=group)) + 
    geom_area()
)
```

Please see below images, I am getting same tooltip value all x-axis. could someone please help me to resolve this.

Area chart with tooltip 1

[image: area chart with tooltip 1]

Area chart with tooltip 2

[image: area chart with tooltip 2]

package versions:
"ggplot2" - "3.4.0"
"plotly" - "4.10.1"

Comment: I tried it with `geom_col` and it works fine, but with `geom_area`, when hovering, only the first value of the group is shown.

Comment: @markhogue, I tried with geom_col, geom_line, geom_point, there is no issues with other geoms. I think the issue is only with geom_area. I didn't have this issue before.

Comment: this looks related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47331323/ggplotly-and-geom-area-display-informations-when-hovering-over-an-area-not-a